# Trouble deleting queried data from MSSQL database using PHP

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I have a problem deleting a queried data from my MSSQL database. What my program does is that you have the option to look for a specific data then if you desire to delete that chosen data you just have to hit the delete button. I have success in showing the queried data but my delete function always fails.

here's my ReadProcess.php code (query function):

```
<?php

include_once("ConnectProcess.php");

class ReadData extends Connection {

  public $Name;

  public function doReadData(){

      $this->Name = $_POST["selectNAME"];

      //declare the SQL statement that will query the database
      $query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.ProfileTable WHERE Name = '$this->Name' OR Sex = '$this->Name' ";

      //keyset cursor needed in order to run sqlsrv_num_rows function
      $params = array();
      $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );

      //execute the SQL query and return records
      $result = sqlsrv_query($this->conn, $query, $params, $options)
         or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

      //Show results in table, if statement for show results of data or no records found
      if(sqlsrv_num_rows($result)>0){
        $o = '<table id="myTable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age </th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            </tr>
            </thead><tbody>';
        while ( $record = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result) )
            {

                $o .= '<tr><td>'.$record ['Name'].'</td><td>'.$record ['Age'].'</td><td>'.$record ['Sex'].'</td></tr>';
            }               
        $o .= '</tbody></table>';

        //result is shown here
        echo $o;

        //delete button form if you want to delete shown data
        $d = '<form method="post" action="DeleteProcess.php">';
        $d .= '<input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete">';
        $d .= '</form>';
        echo $d;

        // Include the class definition:
        require('DeleteProcess.php');

        //if delete is hit
        if (isset($_POST['Delete'])){ 

          //Create a new object:
          $i = new DeleteData();

          //Assign the data:
          $i->setData($this->Name);

          //Connect to Database
          $i->connectDatabase();

          //Start deletion
          $i->doDeleteData();
        }
      }

      else{
        echo "No records found";
      }

    //free result set memory
        sqlsrv_free_stmt($result);

    //close the connection
        sqlsrv_close($this->conn);

  }
}

if (isset($_POST['formView'])){ 
  $i = new ReadData();
  $i->connectDatabase();
  $i->doReadData();
}

?>
```

And here's my DeleteProcess.php code (delete function):

```
<?php

include_once("ReadProcess.php");

class DeleteData extends ReadData{

  public $setName;

  function setData($name = 0) {
         $this->setName = $name;
      }

  public function doDeleteData(){

        //declare the SQL statement that will delete item in the database
        $sql = "DELETE FROM dbo.ProfileTable WHERE Name = '$this->setName'";

        //execute the SQL query and delete records
        $res = sqlsrv_query($this->conn, $sql);

        if (!$res) {
          print("SQL statement failed with error:\n");
          print("   ".sqlsrv_errors()."\n");
        } 
        else {
          $number_of_rows = sqlsrv_rows_affected($res);
          print("$number_of_rows rows deleted.\n");
        }

        //free result set memory
        sqlsrv_free_stmt($res);

        //close the connection
        sqlsrv_close($this->conn);
  }
}

?>
```

Here's the screen of my simple program with a data selected and delete button.

[image: Image screen].

The output is a blank page when hitting the Delete button and no deletion is being done.
can someone help me please? newbie in coding here, Thanks!

Comment: Just a Quick Check: Check whether the data is being deleted in DB table after you press the delete button. select * from dbo.ProfileTable where Name = 'Celina'. If not you need to concentrate bit more on delete operation.

Comment: The data Name = Celina still exist as I query it from the PHP code that I've created and also exist in the MSSQL database when I double checked it.

Comment: @knkarthick24 what do you think is wrong, I'm stuck with this code.. cant move on with this problem.. help please?

Comment: print this string `$sql = "DELETE FROM dbo.ProfileTable WHERE Name = '$this->setName'";` and make sure you are escaping the variable properly and that the SQL doesn't say "`DELETE FROM dbo.ProfileTable WHERE Name = '$this->setName'`"  It wouldn't throw an error, but it also would not delete anything.

Comment: I dont do much PHP but this makes more sense to me.  `$sql = "DELETE FROM dbo.ProfileTable WHERE Name = '"$this->setName"'";`

Comment: @DanielE. printing the string `$sql = "DELETE FROM dbo.ProfileTable WHERE Name = '$this->setName'";` doesn't make any difference and changing it to `$sql = "DELETE FROM dbo.ProfileTable WHERE Name = '"$this->setName"'";` is only going to give an error message.

I dont know what to do :(

Comment: when you print it does it say the appropriate name?

Comment: I echoed the $sql variable and only a blank DeleteProcess.php page is displayed. Am I doing this right?